# RxJs группировка элементов массива в диапазоны дат

Tags: rxjs

Я в процессе изучения RxJs и задался вопросом группировки.
Есть коллекция данных о ежедневных продажах

```
const purchases:any[] = [
    {date:"02.04.2022", purchases:2}, 
    {date:"03.04.2022", purchases:2}, 
    {date:"04.04.2022", purchases:2},
    ...
    {date:"25.09.2022", purchases:2}
]
```

**При помощи каких операторов** я могу группировать ее в зависимости от выбора пользователя

- по неделям

```
[
    {range:"02.04.2022 - 07.04.2022", purchases:27(количество всех продаж за неделю)}, 
    {range:"08.04.2022 - 14.04.2022", purchases:34(количество всех продаж за неделю)}, 
    ...
    {range:"19.09.2022 - 25.09.2022", purchases:102(количество всех продаж за неделю)}
]
```

- по месяцам

```
[
    {range:"02.04.2022 - 02.05.2022", purchases:227(количество всех продаж за месяц)}, 
    {range:"03.05.2022 - 03.06.2022", purchases:341(количество всех продаж за месяц)}, 
    ...
    {range:"25.08.2022 - 25.09.2022", purchases:502(количество всех продаж за месяц)}
]
```

*Может быть, это БРЕД.
И тут не стоит вообще использовать RxJS, и писать все обычно, без реактивности ?*

Comment: Я бы так не упарывался.

Comment: Если этот массив приходит из запроса, и то можно будет его через map преобразовать. Если же сортировка нужна в других кейсах - то тут скорее всего обычный ts. Единствевнное, что из реактивности могу предложить - подписаться на Subject, и в него передавать новый отсортированный массив